# Getting value from text box with JS WYSIWYG editor

Tags: jquery

I have no problem getting a value from a text box with some id:

`$('#foo')`

However, how can I get the **HTML** out from here (live demo): http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinyeditor/ ?

Must be easy.. I've tried:

`$('#editor')`

but it yields

`null`

Any ideas?  Many thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the editor have a documentation?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery library included in that page. Where are you using $('#foo')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nested in an iframe, so you would need to go through that first. Put some id on the iframe then use:

```
$('#iFrameId').contents().find('#editor')
```

However, they must be on the same domain.